# Loading assets in a noscript element

Tags: html, xhtml, cross-browser, noscript

I expect the standard behavior would be to not load any assets in a `<noscript>` element, and a quick cursory test in FF and Chrome proves this to be the case. However, are there any situations where assets (e.g. an image) in a `<noscript>` element, would be loaded when scripts are enabled?

Comment: Don't think it will do this if configured properly: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1 Also just tested this on a site using an image inside a `<noscript>` and no browsers loaded the asset.

Comment: @m90 Thanks. This probably should be an answer not a comment though! Which browsers did you target?

Comment: I was looking at Chrome, FF, Opera and IE. Will put this in an answer right away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to **[W3 specifications](http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/scripts.html#h-18.3.1)**:

> The NOSCRIPT element allows authors to provide alternate content when
>   a script is not executed. The content of a NOSCRIPT element should
>   only be rendered by a script-aware user agent in the following cases:
>   The user agent is configured not to evaluate scripts. The user agent
>   doesn't support a scripting language invoked by a SCRIPT element
>   earlier in the document. User agents that do not support client-side
>   scripts must render this element's contents.

So I guess just like your testing proved: elements inside a `<noscript>` section will not be rendered (i.e. downloaded as well) at all when the client supports `<script>` elements.

I also just tested this on a page of mine that uses an image inside its `<noscript>` part and neither Chrome, FF, Opera or the IE did show any interest in downloading the image.

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on precisely what you mean. Take this markup:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Test Case</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <noscript id="ns">
    </noscript>
    <script>
      var ns = document.getElementById("ns");
      ns.innerHTML = "</noscript><img src='http://www.alohci.net/dummy'>";
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

In Firefox this will result in an `<img>` element inside the `<noscript>` element and the image referenced is fetched from the server.

Notes:
 1. I've no idea why this happens.
 
 2. Only Firefox appears to do this.
 3. I can't imagine any use for this.