# Using google Adwords to tell percentage of people with Javascript turned off

Tags: javascript, google-ads-api

We currently use Google Adwords to detect conversion rates on our site.

We have a piece of script on every page as defined here:

http://support.google.com/adwords/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1722054

This also has a `<noscript>` tag, with a separate call to adservices something like this:

```
<noscript>
  <img height=1 width=1 border=0 
  src="http://www.googleadservices.com/pagead/
  conversion/1234567890/
  ?value=10.0&label=Purchase&script=0">
</noscript>
```

Does anyone know: Can this be used to get a ratio of Javascript/Non-Javascript customers to our site?

Comment: maybe not a full duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10162034/loading-assets-in-a-noscript-element

Comment: Not even close to a duplicate. I am keen on knowing if Google Adwords conversion tracking is able to tell us how many of our customers have JS turned on/off. Otherwise we will have to implement an alternative.